# Tokenizing Ellipsis in a Programming Language to Avoid Floating Points

Tags: floating-point, lex, tokenize, ellipsis

I am designing a language where I want to use .. to define an integer range. The problem is that 0..10 is tokenized as the floats 0. and .10.

How do I allow support this syntax with flex? Is it is simple as making 0. an invalid float?

Comment: Please note that the "Flex" tag refers to Adobe Flex.  Use the "Lex" tag instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really up to how you define your lexer. If you define the ellipsis as being a token made up of two periods, and also define your floating point numbers correctly, there should not be a conflict. Just make sure the token for the ellipsis is defined first in your specification. And, yes, 0. should be an invalid float.

Comment: I changed my lex rules to treat 0. as an invalid number. Since I am basing my lex file off of C's, this must be something valid from a long time ago. Everything works fine now.

Comment: Yes, I have never seen 0. being a valid float in any of the languages I've programmed in. Too bad the parsing rules of lex are a bit restrictive, and I guess Erich Schmidt has better stuff to do than maintain it ;-)

Comment: `1.` is a valid token in Common Lisp, but it actually denotes an integer, not a valid float! `(type-of 123.) -> INTEGER`.

Answer (score 2):

#### March 9, 2012:

If you don't want to make 0. an invalid float, you can use a Lex trailing context:

```
[0-9]+[.]/[^.]  { /* recognize <digits>. only if not followed by another . */ }
```

So this rule will be rejected based on the trailing context mismatch, and the token matches only as an integer constant. Then the next input is `..` which can get recognized as a dot-dot token.

#### March 20, 2012:

I'm going to have to eat my own advice now!

Regression from adding floating point support:

```
$ ./txr -v -l -c '@(bind a (1..3))'
spec:
(((bind a (1.0 0.3))))  # oops, should be (cons 1 3)
bindings:
nil
(a 1.0 0.3)
```

:) Same problem. DOTDOT token in the language, and floats that can begin with a point and end with a point.

My proposed solution is not going to be that straightforward to apply because a floating point token is matched with a single complex regex, where the match for the decimal point is in the middle somewhere, prior to some optional digits and exponent section. The `lex` trailing context can only be at the end.

It will be necessary to change the expression so that it does not recognize `123.` as a valid token, and recognize `123.` with an additional rule which has the trailing context.

Working fix from actual code:

```
diff --git a/parser.l b/parser.l
index d8fd915..449cc14 100644
--- a/parser.l
+++ b/parser.l
@@ -149,8 +149,12 @@ static wchar_t num_esc(char *num)
 %option noinput

 SYM     [a-zA-Z0-9_]+
-NUM     [+\-]?[0-9]+
-FLO     [+\-]?([0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*|[0-9]*[.][0-9]+)([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?
+SGN     [+\-]
+EXP     [eE][+\-]?[0-9]+
+DIG     [0-9]
+NUM     {SGN}?{DIG}+
+FLO     {SGN}?{DIG}*[.]({DIG}+{EXP}?|{EXP})
+FLODOT  {SGN}?{DIG}+[.]
 BSCHR   [a-zA-Z0-9!$%&*+\-<=>?\\^_~]
 BSYM    {BSCHR}({BSCHR}|#)*
 NSCHR   [a-zA-Z0-9!$%&*+\-<=>?\\^_~/]
@@ -190,7 +194,8 @@ UONLY   {U2}{U}|{U3}{U}{U}|{U4}{U}{U}{U}
   return NUMBER;
 }

-<SPECIAL,NESTED,BRACED>{FLO} {
+<SPECIAL,NESTED,BRACED>{FLODOT}/[^.] |
+<SPECIAL,NESTED,BRACED>{FLO}         {
   val str = string_own(utf8_dup_from(yytext));

   if (yy_top_state() == INITIAL
```

So floating constants are of two forms now:

1. optional sign, followed by zero or more digits, and a decimal point followed by either an exponent, or digits and optionally an exponent.
2. digits followed by dot, with a trailing context asserting that the next char is not a dot.

Note how the above demonstrates the technique of multiple patterns (with their own `flex` start states, too) which share the same rule:

```
PATTERN1 |
PATTERN2 |
...
PATTERNN { action; }
```

The patterns can individually have trailing contexts, or not.

P.S. If I change my mind and disallow `123.`, I just remove all traces of `FLODOT`.

### Bug:

This code has to be reversed:

```
<SPECIAL,NESTED,BRACED>{FLODOT}/[^.] |
<SPECIAL,NESTED,BRACED>{FLO}         {
```

I.e.

```
<SPECIAL,NESTED,BRACED>{FLO}         |
<SPECIAL,NESTED,BRACED>{FLODOT}/[^.] {
```

Looks like `flex` is considering the matched trailing context to part of the length of the match. I.e `3.0` is considered a three character match in the `FLODOT` case even though the extracted token is `3.`. So we must put this case second so that `3.0` comes out via the `FLO` match.